# Resources for hand-lettering

Tags: typography, education, resource-recommendations, lettering, calligraphy

What are some of the most useful resources for aspiring graphic designers who want to try hand-lettering?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Lettering-Advertising-Mortimer-Leach/dp/0442247184

Comment: I feel like the "tips" part of this question is too broad as there are tons and it depends on what you have done/can do. You might limit it to resources

Comment: @ZachSaucier I know, I did hesitate before posting. At the same time I feel the "tips" part of the question is the most useful as some of this information may not be found as readily. For example, I'm thinking about things like warming up your arm/hand first, writing with your whole body and not just with your wrist, etc.

Comment: I feel like that's a different question altogether and would be very similar to my [handwriting improvement question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/51925/how-can-i-improve-my-handwriting-ability)

Comment: Ah! Awesome! I'll scope my question to resources and go read your question. Thanks :-)

Comment: This is simply too broad. Start with Google. You'll find plenty.

Comment: Pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working through [Mary Kate McDevitt](http://marykatemcdevitt.com/)'s book [The Hand Lettering Ledger](http://marykatemcdevitt.com/the-shop/hand-lettering-ledger) which has been greatly beneficial to my craftsmanship and has taught me a lot through examples and tips.

The most important way to learn for me is to practice lettering and to do so a lot. Then I look at examples for inspiration, both online and in the world around me, and continue practicing my lettering. The book does a good job of showing different styles of lettering and gives lots of space to create right next to or near the examples.